# Is there any relationship between swt components and html components

Tags: html, swt

Both html and swt are contributing to gui only.
Can anyone explain that if swt components have anything to do with html internally?
If not how these two are building gui components in different way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no connection between SWT and HTML. SWT controls are built using the native GUI API of whichever platform it is run on. So on macOS SWT uses the Cocoa API, on Linux it uses GTK, on Windows it uses the Windows API and so on.

SWT does have a `Browser` control which interfaces to HTML.